# Load an applet in subfolder

Tags: applet, web, subdirectory

I have an applet in the root directory of my website and the applet is used on pages in the root directory and subfolders.
When I open a page of the applet in the root directory it works perfectly. But after I open the page of the subfolder fails to open the applet.
The same thing happens if I open the first page of the subfolder and then the root directory page. The page fault is always the second to open.

Sorry for my English. This was translated by google

Answer (score 0):

Add the `codebase='/'`  attribute/value pair to the applet to ensure the JRE always looks for the Jar relative to the root of the site.  It is the same principle with loading scripts, styles or images into web pages, so it is something you'll need to figure out for web development!